# Prove $\overline{\lim_{n\to \infty }}x_n\cdot\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty }}\frac{1}{x_n}\ge1$.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $0<a\le x_n\le b<\infty $ for all $n\ge1$.

1. Prove $\overline{\lim_{n\to \infty }}x_n\cdot\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty  }}\frac{1}{x_n}\ge1$.
2. Prove there is equality $\iff$ ${x_n}$ converges.

What are those overlines? What do they mean? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with inf\sup?

Comment: I assume they mean [limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior), or $\limsup$ as it is often written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L = \limsup x_n$. Then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ with the property that $x_{n_k} \to L$. Since $0 < a \le L \le b < \infty$ it follows that $\dfrac{1}{x_{n_k}} \to \dfrac 1L$ and $ 0 < \dfrac{1}{L} < \infty$. Consequently $\limsup \dfrac{1}{x_n} \ge \dfrac 1L$ and $$\limsup x_n \cdot \limsup \dfrac{1}{x_n} \ge L \cdot \frac 1L = 1.$$

---

On the other hand, suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is divergent and $L$ is defined as above. There exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ with the property that $x_{n_k} \to L$, and a subsequence $\{y_k\}$ with the property that $y_k \to Y < L$. Then $\limsup \dfrac{1}{x_n} \ge \dfrac{1}{Y}$, and consequently 
$$\limsup x_n \cdot \limsup \dfrac{1}{x_n} \ge L \cdot \frac 1Y = \frac{L}{Y} > 1.$$

Thus if the product equals $1$ the sequence converges.

Comment: Thank you for answering, firstly. That seem promising, furthermore. Can you quote the claim\corollary\theorem according to which there has to be a convergent sub-sequence? And in addition, if there is a subsequence converging to a limit, then it is $limsup$?

Comment: I didn't see them on my teacher notes

Comment: One way to define the limsup is the largest value $L$ for which there exists a subsequence converging to $L$. A bounded sequence always has at least one convergent subsequence--this is the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Also, a bounded sequence diverges if and only if it has subsequences converging to different limits.

Answer (score 1):

Since all $x_n$ are $>a>0$, we can show that $\limsup \frac 1{x_n}=\frac1{\liminf x_n}$:
Let $L$ be an essential upper bound for $\frac1{x_n}$ (i.e., $\frac1{x_n}\le L$ for almost all $n$). Then $\frac 1L$ is an essential lower bound of $x_n$, namely $x_n\ge \frac 1L$ for almost all $n$. Since the converse also holds (where we use that $\frac1{x_n}>\frac1b>0$), we conclude that the supremum of all essential lower bounds of $x_n$ is the reciprocal of the infimum of all essential upper bounds of $\frac 1{x_n}$.

With this at hand (and again using positiveness) the first claim is a restatement of $\liminf\le \limsup$ and the second a restatement of "convergent iff $\limsup=\liminf$".